# Use labeled data from Amazon Sagemaker on local machine without further dependency on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

Is there a possibility to train a network on a segmented semantic segmentation dataset, by downloading the data from Amazon and using it on your local machine, without any dependencies on AWS? And how would this be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The data generated from the labeling will be exported to an output bucket. From here, the images can be downloaded as trimaps for Semantic Segmentation.